# Troubleshooting AzerothCore: FactionTemplate Changes Not Affecting In-Game Interactions

Tags: azerothcore

AzerothCore FactionTemplate not reflecting in-game

Got a question about `FactionTemplate`

In `Unit.cpp` there’s a method called `SetFaction()` that sets the data from the ID from the FactionTemplate in the database.

If you modify this method so that it returns `FACTION_FRIENDLY` (which is ID `35`) for faction ID `11` or `12` (which is Stormwind) then that faction is friendly to everyone, especially a horde player.

So my question is: I tried adjusting the FactionTemplate in the acore_world database so that the template for `11` and `12` is the same as 35. But in-game all that does is make them not hostile (still red). Whereas adjusting the SetFaction method makes them friendly (green) and interactable.

Is there something here I’m missing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.